# How to create a Kate highlight syntax to CSV files

Tags: csv, editors, syntax-highlighting, kate

I'm working with CSV files, and I'm using vim because of the rainbow CSV plugin that makes the editing easier:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4598

But I prefer using Kate, and as I did not find anything on the Internet like it. I'm trying to do a syntax highlight myself, but I'm not familiar with the file format and do not know if it is possible to do something similar to rainbow CSV on Kate.
I was trying to do an itemData for each word position, but it did not work as I expected.

```xml
<context attribute="Normal" lineEndContext="#stay" name="normal">
<RegExpr attribute="Comment" context="#stay" String="^\s*#.*$" />
<RegExpr attribute="Comma0" context="#stay" String="^.*," minimal="true" />
<RegExpr attribute="Comma1" context="#stay" String=",.*," minimal="true" />
</context>
<itemDatas>
<itemData name="Comma0" defStyleNum="dsComma0" color="#02BCFF" />
<itemData name="Comma1" defStyleNum="dsComma1" color="#81FF4B" />
<itemData name="Comma2" defStyleNum="dsComma2" color="#FF4848" />
<itemData name="Comment" defStyleNum="dsComment"/>
<itemData name="Normal" defStyleNum="dsNormal"/>
</itemDatas>
```

I want each word to have a different colour.

Text example:

```
word0,word1,word2,word3,word4,...,wordN
```

If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it.